# httpClient.executeMethod throws unexpected 404 - unexplained truncated url

Tags: java, http, soap, apache-httpclient-4.x

Urls used here are for illustration only due to privacy of the problem, i'm facing.

My soapAction url is well formed, and my request is a well formed soap request too. What bugs me is that my url is `https://www.macy.com/we.like.to.buy.discounts` and this is the 404 error i get, basically the soap response was truncating my original url:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /we.like.to.buy.discounts was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Digging a little by debugging into the code, it seems like the `post` object has a `path` attribute with a value of `/we.like.to.buy.discounts` which was the *incorrect* url and a `HttpHost` attribute of `www.macy.com`. Which I don't understand why the client is not sending the full url and just the truncated one. Please help.

The original code is here:

```
public static void service(String request, String webServiceURL)
            throws IOException {
        boolean status = false;
        String soapAction = webServiceURL;
        HttpClient client= new HttpClient();        
        PostMethod post= new PostMethod(soapAction);
        client.executeMethod(post);
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            InputStreamRequestEntity requestEntity = new InputStreamRequestEntity(is, "text/xml");
            post.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
            client.executeMethod(post);         
            String soapRes = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
            System.out.println("Soap Response:" + soapRes);

            if (!soapRes.contains("YourMAMA")) {
                status = false;
            } else {
                status = true;
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
            post.releaseConnection();
        } 

    }
```

Comment: When I visit https://www.macy.com/we.like.to.buy.discounts in my browser, I get a 404.

Comment: its an illustrated example, thats not the real url of my problem